# Google Sheets permissions

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, permissions, google-drive-sharing

I built two separate spreadsheets in Google Drive and spreadsheet "A" has a script that when run, will copy the input data into spreadsheet "B". When I test it, it works perfectly. But I have other users that only have access to spreadsheet "A". When they run the script it doesn't work because they don't have permission to spreadsheet "B", but I don't want to give them the historical data that's saved in spreadsheet "B".

The error message is:

> Document *ID* is missing (perhaps it was deleted?)

How do I get through this?

<sub>I made a Demo copy that can be accessed: [demo copy](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JW9DFWs69DSUDCI3RCHCA1_y3EzvcQUQDXpgMABVhC8/edit?usp=sharing)</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Authorization for Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization) it's not possible because for Standalone, add-on, or bound to Docs, Sheets, or Forms the script run as the user at keyboard. The alternatives is to convert your script to a web app or to a Installable trigger.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry this is not possible yet in Google spreadsheet :(. But I am not sure if you have though of this solution yet;

You could make a duplicate of both the spreadsheet b and a so that " the other people" can't see your historical data.

Only issue with this is you would be remaking the whole thing:(

Hope this help!